# "Non-breaking space (U+00A0) used instead of regular space" warning in Xcode

Tags: xcode

When typing a <kbd>space</kbd> character in Xcode, a warning appears sometimes:

> Non-breaking space (U+00A0) used instead of regular space

Earlier Xcode versions display these messages:

> Treating Unicode character as whitespace

or

> Invalid character in source file

If I re-write the character, the warning disappears. What causes this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That happens to me when I type too fast and accidentally hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> while pressing down <kbd>Space</kbd>. This creates a non-breaking space (`0xA0`) which is not recognized as a valid space character by Xcode.

For a (hacky) solution, I've remapped this combination to **Insert Tab** inside Xcode's **Settings/Key Bindings**, so it enters a tabulator character instead.

Comment: But on copy pasting the code,the above warning may come for thousands of lines sometimes.its not easy to rewrite the whole

Comment: In case there is someone who wonders how to fix this in VsCode go to open keyboard shortcuts(JSON) then put this shortcut there. This basically types a space instead of non-breaking space when you press option space  {
    "key": "alt+space",
    "command": "type",
    "args": {
      "text": " "
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }