# Removing Unicode character in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unicode

I often use OneNote for sample/template code which I can refer for any project. But When I copy from OneNote to Xcode I get below warning "Treating Unicode character as whitespace".

[image: Xcode Editor Snapshop]

Though this is just a warning I like to see my code editor window warnings free. Is there any way to replace these Unicode character?

Comment: Does Xcode's find-and-replace function not work?

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. But is there any way to avoid it while pasting text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Non-breaking space (U+00A0) used instead of regular space" warning in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445481/non-breaking-space-u00a0-used-instead-of-regular-space-warning-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

That happens to me, even converting the unicode text format didn't resolve this issue.

For a (hacky) solution, paste your code in apple-mail new message first, then copy and paste to Xcode, will correct this issue.